# Ajax function with multiple buttons for a .click event

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a form with two buttons that have the same name and id (don't ask me why, I didn't create the form lol). I am trying to use Ajax .click function to run when the buttons are clicked. However, the function is only working with the "Approve" button and not the "Forward" button. Is there anyway to call this function from the Forward button?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btnApprove").click(function(){
   alert("Button was clicked.");
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="btnApprove" value="Approve" tabindex="1102" />

    <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="btnApprove" value="Forward" tabindex="1102" />
</body>
</html>
```

I modified the code from http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDs must be unique. Even if they aren't unique, jQuery only selects the first occurence.
You should change the IDs to be unique.

But anyway, you select per name instead:

```
$("input[name=btnSubmit]").click(function(){
    alert("Button was clicked.");
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the help. They won't let me change the IDs, so this will have to work.

Answer (score 0):

No two elements on a page should have the same id.

$("#btnApprove") maps the the native `document.getElementById` method which returns the first instance of an element of that id, so the event is only being bound to the first button

Answer (score 0):

add a class attribute to both buttons, putting them in the same class
then you should be able to do something like

```
  $('.NameOfClassHere').click(function(){
```

or

```
  $('.NameOfClassHere').live('click', function () {
```

This will work for the click event of all buttons in that class, so saves you from using duplicate code. Also, agreed that you should not use duplicate IDs. Hopefully this helps.